# How to use the same variable when using .vue component in external .js files?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a .vue single file component which has too many lines so I'm trying to seperate it into .js files. I can achieve this with help from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54430191/how-to-separate-the-methods-of-a-vue-component-in-an-external-js-file).

However, I'm still stuck whentrying to use a variable from different files.

So, this what the old `foobar.vue` looks like

**foobar.js**

```
<script>
let foo; // there is one global variable (somehow I have to do this way)

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      bar: [1, 2, 3, 4],
    }
  },
  methods: {
    baz() {
      foo = 'some text';
      this.bar.push(5);
    },
    qux() {
      foo += 'lorem ipsum';
      this.bar.shift(0);
    },
  }
}
</script>
```

---

Now, I seperate into two files, `baz.js`, `qux.js`, and they look like this:

**foobar.vue**

```
<script src="@/baz.js"></script>
<script src="@/qux.js"></script>
<script>
import { baz } from '@/baz';
import { qux } from '@/qux';

let foo; // I want to manipulate this from external files

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      bar: [0, 1, 2, 3], // I also want to manipulate this from external files
    }
  },
  methods: {
    baz,
    qux,
  }
}
</script>
```

**baz.js**

```
function baz() {
  foo = 'some text'; //foo undefined
  this.bar.push(5); //this.bar undefined
}

export { baz };
```

**qux.js**

```
function qux() {
  foo += 'lorem ipsum'; // foo undefined
  this.bar.shift(0); //this.bar undefined
}

export { qux };
```

---

Obviously, it doesn't work because `baz()` and `qux()` cannot see `foo` and `this.bar` (in `data()`). So, what should I do in order to be able to see and manipulate `foo` and `bar`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at [Mixins](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html).

Here's a simple example you can try:

```
// mixin.js
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            mixinData: 1
        }
    },
    methods: {
        printMixinData() {
            console.log(this.mixinData)
        },
        printDataFromVueFile() {
            console.log(this.vueData)
        }
    }
}

// YourVueFile.vue
<template>
    <input type="button" @click="printMixinData" value="Print Mixin Data">
    <input type="button" @click="printDataFromVueFile" value="Print value from .vue File">
</template>

<script>
    import myMixin from './mixin.js'
    export default {
        mixins: [myMixin], // important line here
        data() {
            return {
                vueData: 2
            },
        }   
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, Vue offers `$root` Instance to access variable & methods at the global level. Plus the instance is reactive as well.

Let's say if your both components `foo` & `bar` is binding to the main component called `App`.

Now define a variable inside the data object of the `App` component.

In order to access data from the `App` component, you can to access it from `$root` from Vue.

```js
const Foo = {
  template: '<span> {{this.$root.foo}} {{this.$root.from}} </span>'
};

const Baz = {
  template: '<span> {{this.$root.baz}} {{this.$root.from}} </span>'
};

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    foo: 'Foo',
    baz: 'Baz',
    from: 'from app component'
  },
  components: {
    Foo,
    Baz
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <Foo></Foo>
  <br />
  <Baz></Baz>
</div>
```

**NOTE: $root to works with .vue file**

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

Use `window.foo` - store variable in global scope
Or add `common.js` file and there add:

```
export var foo;
```

and in **baz.js** and **qux.js** import them

```
import { foo } from "./common.js"
```